# Problem with upgrading Ubuntu

Tags: upgrade, ppa, repository

I tried updating Ubuntu 12.04 by following the guide at http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/upgrade but I received this error message:

[image: http://i.imgur.com/rcJ46.png]

What do I do?

Comment: What happens when you check your internet connection?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either you get the keys or you just disable the ppa for the upgrade to 12.04/10.

to disable the ppa open up the **"software sources"**, which you will find with the unity dash, and uncheck spotify's repository in **"Other Software"**.

[image]

after this is done, try the system upgrade again using the "Update Manager" which also can be found in the dash

If you want to get the new public key for spotify instead, you have to open a terminal and use these 2 commands

gpg --keyserver subkeys.pgp.net --recv-key 94558F59

gpg --export  94558F59 | sudo apt-key add -

after you successfully executed these commands try the upgrade again.

Answer (score 1):

> The solution is simple.Take the first key you have problem with, for
>   example 082CCEDF94558F59, take the last 8 symbols (in this case -
>   94558F59) and run the following in the terminal: Code:
>
> ```
> gpg --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv 94558F59
> gpg --export --armor 94558F59 | sudo apt-key add -
> ```
>
> Then repeat this step with every problematic key.

i found it here [GPG error: http://ppa.launchpad.net lucid Release: The following signatures couldn](http://stream-recorder.com/forum/w-gpg-error-http-ppa-launchpad-net-t6741.html?s=c5b3ddee5ed544e029e2564073230a4c&)